# Assigning return value to a reference type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

If you create a class in .NET it will be a reference type. In this example I’m setting the name of MyClass inside of SomeMethod. Now inside the Main method I do not really need to assign back the return value from SomeMethod because the parameter passed in is a reference type. I’m wanting the instance in the main method to have the new updated name “John” and it does.

I often assignee back the return value anyway for readability, even though this isn’t needed to get the updated properties reassigned to my origin instance in main. My assumption is that the compiler is smart enough not to recreate a new reference of MyClass inside the Main method. Is that true? Or does the compiler actually create a new reference and pointing to the updated values when assigning itself the return value?

```
//My class will be a reference type
public class MyClass 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    //Main method of application
    public void Main()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        //return value back to itself
        myClass = SomeMethod(myClass);
    }

    public MyClass SomeMethod(MyClass myClass)
    {
        myClass.name = "John";
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

Here is the IL

```
    instance void Main1 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class Test.MyClass myClass
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void Test.MyClass::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldarg.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: call instance class Test.MyClass Test.Main::SomeMethod(class Test.MyClass)
    IL_000d: stloc.0
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method Main::Main1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes the compiler is smart enough to not reassign the return value to the same object. If we open your code with Reflector or dotPeek, your code :

```
public void Main()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    //return value back to itself
    myClass = SomeMethod(myClass);
}
```

is simply transform to :

```
public void Main()
{
    this.SomeMethod(new MyClass());
}
```

Even if we do something with the reassign variable, it is still remove by the compiler. For example, the compiler transform this :

```
public void Main()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    //return value back to itself
    myClass = SomeMethod(myClass);

    Console.WriteLine(myClass.name);
}
```

to that :

```
public void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.SomeMethod(new MyClass()).name);
}
```

But like Lews Therin and Robert Jeppesen said, you shouldn't do that because it is bad practice and could lead to misunderstanding

Comment: Are you sure it transforms to "this.SomeMethod"? Considering that Main is a static method? Although I notice that you omitted the "static" keyword (which in that case your answer is probably right).

Comment: You are right, I created the Main class. But the compiler is doing the same thing with static method (without the "this"). And the OP didn't had static method too

Comment: Yes looks like you are correct. I added the IL int the original post.

Comment: The compiler may very well optimize it out *in this specific instance* because it can determine that the return value isn't used, so the entire local variable isn't needed, but if you use this pattern everywhere then it won't always be able to make that optimization.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't create a new reference.

But there isn't any point in returning it either. This should suffice:

```
 public void SomeMethod(MyClass myClass)
 {
    myClass.name = "John";

 }
```

The above is natural and actually less convoluted than the way you propose.

Comment: I understand its not needed. As I stated it just seems more readable to me.

Comment: Really? I disagree. Each to their own I guess.

Comment: @Thomas Returning the modified instance indicates to the consumer of this method that it is a new instance, and the passed-in instance will be left unharmed, which is clearly not the case. Harmful!

Comment: Remember when you pass in an object to a method, you're really just passing in a pointer to that object. In order to create a new object, you need to either create your own cloning methods, or create a new one (hence the word new)

Answer (score 1):

Classes are passed as reference to methods, so your are modifying the same thing as you are returning.

> When an object based on a reference type is passed to a method, no
>   copy of the object is made. Instead, a reference to the object being
>   used as a method argument is made and passed. Changes made through
>   this reference will therefore be reflected in the calling method.
>   
>   Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114(v=vs.80).aspx

Regarding the readability: your method should always be self-explanatory. The name of the method should in my opinion say something about what it does.

```
void AddClientContextToContainer(Container destination)
```

Comment: I think your missing my question. I understand the class itself is not passed, its a reference type as I mentioned. I was asking if in the main method by assigning back the return value, does the compiler create another 'reference' in the main method.

Comment: `Classes are passed by reference to methods`.  No they aren't.  Classes *are* references, and they are passed by *value* (unless you use ref/out) to methods.  The value that is copied is simply a reference.

Comment: @Servy You're right. They are passed **as** reference, not 'by' reference.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are creating one *instance* of the object.  The actual instance is created via `new`.  A reference is essentially just an integer (32 bit on a 32 bit system, 64 bit on a 64 bit system).  That integer refers to the location of the object instance in memory.  "Creating a new reference" is essentially the same amount of work as creating a new integer (meaning very, very little; it's about the smallest possible unit of work a computer can do).

Your code, as opposed to the `void` alternative, will be performing two (redundant) copies of references.  (Once to copy the method parameter to the return value on the stack, and then again from that return value back to the original variable.)

The actual amount of additional work there is minuscule.  It exists, but it's really quite tiny.  The concern here should simply be one of readability.  If you find that code easier to read and understand, then fine.  Just note that it's a pattern that is normally only used when `MyClass` is immutable, where the return value is a reference to a new instance rather than the one that was passed in.  This is likely to cause confusion for other people reading your code.  If they incorrectly assume that the object is immutable it could lead to...bad things.

Others have suggested making the method return void, but I'd say that it might just make sense for the class to become immutable.  You're already following a more immutable pattern.

Comment: This was my concern. Does another reference get created in the main method, which you are claiming it does (do you have a reference, no pun intended). This seemed the naturally correct answer at first glance. I was wondering if the compiler was smart enough to know it does not need to create another reference here as it is technically not necessary.

Comment: @Thomas It's important to differentiate "reference" from "instance".  You are performing copies of "references", but you are not creating, nor copying, any actual "instances".  Copying a reference is just the same as copying a single integer; it is the same amount of work (as I said, that amount is **tiny** regardless of the size of the object that it references).